# How can I type the "at" @ symbol on a Spanish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, troubleshooting

I just finished installing Ubuntu on my AMD Athlon, but I cannot type the "at" sign. I'm from Peru and my Keyboard is Spanish. I have tried using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, but nothing happens.
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

The unicode character entry keyboard sequence is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>hex value</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> so the `@` sign would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>40</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You might want to check the keyboard locale settings in the keyboard layout pane of the settings center to make sure you have the right layout.

◕‿◕

Answer (score 3):

The @ is on the '2' key on a Spanish keyboard. Do this: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>gr</kbd> (near the space bar) and the 2 key.

Similar to this is '€': <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>gr</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

The there is:

- á
- é
- í
- ó
- ú

To do this, near return the is <kbd>ç</kbd> to the left of this key is <kbd>´¨</kbd>.
Press once then the appropriate vowel.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is the way to input `@` from a Spanish keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above work on mine, so I use the onscreen keyboard, which accessed on my HP just to left of time and date at bottom of screen

Comment: An onscreen keyboard is a good alternative. Please describe with more details how to get it and how to use it (to type @). Add a screenshot picture if you wish :-)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> at the same time.
And it is not the Spanish key board.
It is the latino america keyboard.